# Clear Python cachetools manually

Tags: python, python-3.x, caching

In this class I have a method which I cache its result using `cachetools`:

```
from cachetools import cached, TTLCache

class Log:

    @cached(TTLCache(maxsize=200, ttl=300))
    def get_sessions(self, user_id):
        query = """select * from comprehensive_log.sessions where user_id = %s order by start DESC limit 50"""
        user_sessions = self.fetch_data_from_log(query, (user_id,))
        return user_sessions

    def get_last_session(self, user_id_arg):
        user_sessions = self.get_sessions(user_id_arg)

    ...
```

I call this class in this file `sessions.py`:

```
from src.OO_log import Log

log_object = Log()

def get_data():
    user_list = get_user_list_from_database()
    for user in user_list:
        log_object.get_last_session(user.id)
    return True
...
```

Now I use `get_data` method of `sessions.py` in my `main.py`:

```
from sessions import get_data()

while the_end:
  result = get_data()
  # How can I clear cache here before going for the next loop?
```

I want to clear the cache after the end of each while loop.

#### What have I tried?

I tried changing the `Log` class `__init__` like this:

```
class Log:

    def __init__(self):
        self.get_sessions = cached(TTLCache(maxsize=200, ttl=300))(self.get_sessions)

    def get_sessions(self, user_id):
        query = """select * from comprehensive_log.sessions where user_id = %s order by start DESC limit 50"""
        user_sessions = self.fetch_data_from_log(query, (user_id,))
        return user_sessions
```

and deleting `result` in `while` loop:

```
while the_end:
    result = get_data()
    del result
```

But none of them helped.

So how can I clear python `cachetools` manually or is there anything else I can do to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can store the sessions in a variable outside the class:

```
_sessions_cache = TTLCache(maxsize=200, ttl=300)
```

and then just call:

```
_sessions_cache.clear()
```

Comment: Note that the [official docs](https://cachetools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/?highlight=clear) state that the `clear` method should be thread safe (use a lock before clearing the cache).

Comment: `cachetools.func` decorators are thread-safe by default and have a `cache_clear()` method that can be used on the cache
https://cachetools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/?highlight=clear#cachetools.func.fifo_cache